# customunboundcolumndata event not firing in DEVExpress gridview

Tags: events, devexpress

I have been struggling with the below code snippet. "CustomUnboundColumnData" event is not firing.

```
 Protected Sub gvAlertReport_CustomUnboundColumnData(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As    DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewColumnDataEventArgs)
    If e.Column.FieldName = "Active" Then
        Dim val As String = e.Value
        Dim img As New ImageButton()
        Select Case val
            Case "False"
                img.ImageUrl = "Images/gray_bell.png"
                img.Attributes.Add("", "")
            Case "True"
                img.ImageUrl = "Images/red_bell.png"
                img.Attributes.Add("", "")
            Case Else

        End Select
     End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: is you grid in a detail row of other grid? if not, can you try placing onCustomUnboundColumnData="gvAlertReport_CustomUnboundColumnData" in your Grid Tag?

Answer (score 2):

The CustomUnboundColumnData event is only triggered if there is a column in the ASPxGridView which is designed as an Unbound Column.  To learn how this can be done, please refer to the [Unbound Columns Overview](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3764) topic.  Also, please make certain that the  gvAlertReport_CustomUnboundColumnData is the actual event handler for the ASPxGridView.